# Graphics Card Alienware area 51 m15x laptop

Tags: graphics-card

I am trying to troubleshoot to isolate the problem (This laptop was dropped) all the lights turn on but the screen is black, so it seems to be the graphics card. I have another alienware laptop that has the same slot(MXM Mobile PCI-Express Module) and it seems that I can put the working graphics card in the broken laptop. I dont really know what messes up when a laptop is dropped, and my worry is that if I install the good graphics card onto the broken laptop that it might fry the card? Can such a thing happen, or am I just being paranoid?

(And for those saying that you cant change graphics cards on laptops, yes you can change the graphics cards on alienwares since they have the slot I mentioned previously).

Answer (score 0):

My friend is having a similar problem on his M15x.  Before you blame the video card, try connecting a regular monitor to the VGA output on your laptop.  If your VGA-out works (which it did for my friend) the culprit is the screen itself, or more likely the connection between the video card and the screen.